# How to know Linux processes running in current directory

Tags: linux, server, command

Now I am running few processes from different directories . I need to kill a process from a particular directory.Now i am in that directory.How to kill all processes inside that directory using a single command.

Comment: Do you mean you want to find all processes whose current working directory is a specific path? How will you distinguish between processes that was started with that path as the current working directory, and those processes who set it later? And what if a process was started with the CWD as the path, and then changed it?

Comment: No Issue even if it started from another path.I need all processes currently in that path.